# Jest test coverage for VueJS application with Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, test-coverage

I have VueJS application written with NuxtJS. This setup causes that I have many files index.vue in different directories.
When I run the testing suite with commend `jest --no-cache --watch --coverage` only 1 file index.vue has being picked up by coverage results.

my configuration of jest in package.json is:

```
"jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+.vue$": "vue-jest",
      "^.+.js$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.{js,vue}",
      "!**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "coverageReporters": [
      "text"
    ],
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "jest-extended"
}
```

and results show only coverage for 1 index.vue file (even I have multiple of them as well other .vue files).

What configuration option I need to add to run coverage for all .vue files?

Comment: Could you show coverage table and folder structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At a first sight, I would expect to see Jest's [`moduleFileExtensions config option`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulefileextensions-array-string) in place like:

```
 "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "json", "jsx", "node", "vue"],
    // The rest of your config...
  }
```

The option tells Jest which file extensions are used by the modules of your application.

Comment: This unfortunately didn't work for me. Only `index.vue` is getting coverage and I have the exact same config.

Comment: Fixed this by exporting the Vue instance in the script section of the Vue files.